# Prove that $\text{Id}_{\text{dom }\mathcal R}⊆\mathcal R^{-1}∘\mathcal R$ and $\text{Id}_{\text{rank }\mathcal R}⊆\mathcal R∘\mathcal R^{-1}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations

**Definition**

A set $\mathcal R$ is a binary relation if any its element is an ordered pair.

**Definition**

Given a relation $\mathcal R$ the subset $\text{dom }\mathcal R$ of $\bigcup\big(\bigcup\mathcal R\big)$ whose elements are the first coordinates of $\mathcal R$ is called the domain of $\mathcal R$.

**Definition**

Given a relation $\mathcal R$ the subset $\text{ran}\;\mathcal R$ of $\bigcup\big(\bigcup\mathcal R\big)$ whose elements are the second coordinates of $\mathcal R$ is called the range of $\mathcal R$.

So with this definitions is not hard to show that
$$
\mathcal R\subseteq\text{dom }\mathcal R\times\text{ran }\mathcal R
$$
so that we can give the following definition.

**Definition**

If $\mathcal R$ is a relation then the inverse relation $\mathcal R^{-1}$ of $\mathcal R$ is the relation defined by the identity
$$
\mathcal R^{-1}:=\{(x,y)\in\text{dom }\mathcal R\times\text{ran }\mathcal R:y\mathcal Rx\}
$$

Finally we give the following definition

**Definition**

If $\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal S$ are two relations. their composition $\mathcal S\circ\mathcal R$ is the relation defined through the identity
$$
\mathcal S\circ\mathcal R:=\{(x,y)\in\text{dom }\mathcal R\times\text{ran}\;\mathcal S:x\mathcal Rz\wedge z\mathcal Sy\,\,\,\text{for any }z\in\text{ran}\;\mathcal R\times\text{dom }\mathcal S\}
$$

So if $\text{Id}_{\text{dom }\mathcal R}$ and $\text{Id}_{\text{rank }\mathcal R}$ are the identity relations over $\text{dom }\mathcal R$ and $\text{ran}\;\mathcal R$ respectively then I ask to show that
$$
\text{Id}_{\text{dom }\mathcal R}\subseteq\mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal R\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\text{Id}_{\text{ran }\mathcal R}\subseteq\mathcal R\circ\mathcal R^{-1}
$$

So could anyone help me, please?

Comment: You mean "range", not "rank".

Comment: Sorry, I am studying set theory from a spanish text: evidently I got wrong translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the definitions and the usual strategy for proving that a set inclusion holds: To prove that $A \subseteq B$, show that for any $a \in A$ we also have that $a \in B$.

If you want to show

$$
\text{Id}_{\text{dom}\;\mathcal R}\subseteq\mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal R
$$

you must show that for any $(x,x) \in \text{Id}_{\text{dom}\;\mathcal R}$ we also have that $(x,x) \in \mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal R$. Since $(x,x) \in \text{Id}_{\text{dom}\;\mathcal R}$, we know that $x \in \text{dom}\;\mathcal{R}$. This then implies that there exists a $y$ such that $(x,y) \in \mathcal{R}$. And therefore $(y,x) \in \mathcal{R}^{-1}$. The result now follows by the definition of relation composition. The other inclusion is proved in the same way.

Comment: Okay, so what I wrote in my answer is right?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes.

Comment: Okay, question upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Definition**

Let be $\mathcal R$ a relation.

1. The image of a set $A$ through $\mathcal R$ is the set
   $$
   \mathcal R[A]:=\{y\in\text{ran }R:x\mathcal Ry\,\,\,\text{for any }x\in\text{dom }\mathcal R\}
   $$
2. The preimage of a set $B$ through $\mathcal R$ is the set
   $$
   \mathcal R^{-1}[B]:=\{x\in\text{dom }\mathcal R:x\mathcal Ry\,\,\,\text{for any }y\in B\}
   $$

---

---

So by the preceding definition we conclude that
$$
x\mathcal Ry\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,y\mathcal R^{-1}x
$$
for any $y\in\mathcal R\big[\{x\}\big]$ from which it follows that
$$
x\big(\mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal R\big)x
$$
for any $x\in\text{dom }\mathcal R$ and thus we finally conclude that
$$
\text{id}_{\text{dom }\mathcal R}\subseteq\mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal R
$$
Moreover by the definition of $\mathcal R^{-1}\big[\{y\}\big]$ for any $y\in\text{ran }\mathcal R$ with analogous argumentation we conclude that
$$
\text{id}_{\text{ran }\mathcal R}\subseteq\mathcal R\circ\mathcal R^{-1}
$$